# JPA/Hibernate call SQL Server Stored procedure with default values for paramerers

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa, micronaut-data

I am calling a sql server stored procedure with 10 parameters. The first 2 parameters expects values to be passed, all the others have default values set. I am calling the stored procedure as shown below -

```
entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("my_proc")
    .registerStoredProcedureParameter("param1", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
    .
    . 
    . // register all 10 parameters
    .setParamater("param1", value1)
    .setParameter("param2", value2) // set values only for the first 2 parameters
    .execute();
```

When I run this with `param_null_passing=false`, I get an error - `Value not set for parameter null`.

When `param_null_passing=true`, procedure is called but `null` values are passed for parameters with default values.

How can the procedure be called without explicitly passing values for parameters with default values?

Thank you.